# How do you make custom shaped buttons in html/css?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm wondering how sites such as Facebook, and TeamTreehouse make their navigation buttons custom shaped.
Like this:

(From teamtreehouse.com)
https://gyazo.com/47e09a6d70019b5b8d93549af20f1a9c,
and this,
(From facebook.com)
https://gyazo.com/32de164e941c4f80355bd3d0b6045abe .

Can someone please explain to me how you make these custom shaped buttons? :)
Thank you!

Note: Sorry for using links instead of images, don't have enough reputation...

Comment: [Icons: How does a developer with no design skill make his/her application icons look pretty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729/icons-how-does-a-developer-with-no-design-skill-make-his-her-application-icons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use buttons for that.
It can be a simple A tag and give the with, size and background using CSS. You can also give :hover status with this technique.

```
<a href="whatever.html" class="icon"></a>

<style type="text/css">
.icon{
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-image:url(your-image.gif) bottom;
}

.icon:hover{
    background-position:top;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple quick tip is use bootstrap. And then customise.
If you want to create your own button style from scratch use CSS properties like -moz-